# How can get data unit by ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system

Is there a way to according to the data's spatial reference to get the unit of data, for example: wgs1984 → Decimal degrees, UTM54 → Meters.

Comment: I just found SpatialReference object have a linearUnitName property, The unit of data can get through it.

Answer (score 2):

I found the projected coordinate system has linearUnitName property, and angularUnitName property is empty, and for the geographic coordinate system is just the opposite. so can get unit by follow codes.

```
sr = arcpy.Describe(fc).SpatialReference
unit = sr.linearUnitName
if unit == '':
  unit = sr.angularUnitName
```